# Pydantic add field to model after a model validation (add filed to incoming model)

Tags: python, pydantic

I have an incoming pydantic User model.
To add field after validation I'm converting it to dict and adding a field like for a regular dict.

```
user = employee.dict()
user.update({'invited_by': 'some_id'})
db.save(user)
```

Is there a shorter AND CLEANEST way to add a field? Because even for myself it's no such clear, every time that I meeting this code (that wrote by myself) I thinking "Why I'm converting model to dict as separate instruction/line if I can do it inside `save` function (`db.save(user)`)

Comment: `db.save(user.copy(update={'invited_by': 'some_id'})`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have access to model definition, you could allow extra fields in the model [Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/).

```
import pydantic
from pydantic import Extra


class A(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: str = "qwer"

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.allow

a = A()
a.b = 1234
print(a)  # a = 'qwer' b = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue, but the given solution did not work for me. I have figured out that Pydantic made some updates and when using Pydantic V2, you should allow extra using the following syntax, it should work

```py
import pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel , ConfigDict


class A(BaseModel):
    a: str = "qwer"

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#extra-fields